# Internet trouble: some things are fine, some things aren't

Tags: windows-7, windows, chatzilla

In my browser (firefox) everything is normal. I can visit every site I want to, load/play flash videos etc.

But I seem unable to be on irc (chatzilla), I can't download anything (qbittorrent, I can dl the .torrent files) and I can't connect to the steam network.

I use windows 7 here.

Anyone has had this issue or knows what I can do?

Edit: I was able to connect to steam. But irc and dl-ing are still not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This probably indicates that you are NATed somewhere along your connection without UPnP, or the ports wanted by ChatZilla/qBittorrent are explicitly blocked by your administrator.

Ask whoever administrates your network to set up UPnP, or, failing that, triggered forwarding for your MAC address.

Comment: The thing I forgot to mention: everything was fine yesterday, I don't think settings were changed since then.

Comment: I still suspect it is NAT/UPnP related. If you're sure nothing was changed, it should still work ;)

Comment: Actually, I'm a bit confused about your edit re: steam. Does this mean that you can *sometimes* connect to Steam, but sometimes not?

Comment: No, at the time I was writing the post, I couldn't connect.
After posting, I tried everything again, and I was on steam.
So steam is fine now, don't ask me why :)

Comment: It's not UPnP related. UPnP helps when you need port forwardings TO the INSIDE. NAT helps port forwarding to the OUTSIDE. NAT does connecting to the outside, UPnP is not necessary and only puts manual port forwardings into firewalls (if they support it) so your PC can be connected to from anywhere

Comment: Your point? That is a requirement of the majority of these programs.

Comment: Btw, there is still something wrong with my steam ;)
But soon i'll install new OS's so I'll take a closer look to it if it's necessary then. But thanks anyway, neurolysis.

Comment: Strangely, everything works today :)
I didn't change anything.